# Saving a variable after the python code has run to access it when code is to be run again

Tags: python, mysql, pickle

I am trying to retrieve data from a mysql server, run a code using the data retrieved, then push the data back to the database on different columns. I have managed to get all of that working as seen in my code attached.

However, new rows will be added constantly to the database and i don't want to have to load the entire database everytime. I want the code to only run on the new rows that have been added. Therefore, i am trying save the student_id and retrieve it somehow and the beginning of the code.

I tried different methods and i even tried pickle but i was left with little luck. The aim is to have the code run continuously on a remote server so i would really appreciate if someone can help me out as it will help me achieve my task.

Note: This is only dummy data and code but is pretty much the method of what i am trying to achieve.

```
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
import time
import pickle

filename = 'saved_id'
infile = open(filename,'rb')
st_id = pickle.load(infile)
print(number)

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password='password',
                               host="demo.mysql.database.azure.com", port=3306)

conn.autocommit = True

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("USE testdb;")

while True:

   outfile = open(filename,'wb')

   cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id >= {st_id};")

   myresult = np.array(cursor.fetchall())

   print (myresult)

   for row in myresult:

      mark_1 = np.random.randint(0,100)
      mark_2 = np.random.randint(0,100)
      mark_3 = np.random.randint(0,100)

      iid = row[0]
      pickle.dump(iid,outfile)
      outfile.close()

      cursor.execute(f"UPDATE student SET grade_1 = {mark_1}, grade_2 = {mark_2}, grade_3 = {mark_3} WHERE student_id = {iid};")


time.sleep(5)
```

I Think the problem is that when i initially run the code the pickle value doesn't have an input, and when i try to use a standard variable method it will not be defined which will result in some kind of error as well.

Please also do let me know if there are any aspects of my code that could be improved for speed, efficiency!

Comment: Why don't you store the variable in an own table in the database so that the data is consistent?

Comment: You can save the id's to a txt file and keep updating the file every run. Load the file in when you want to extract the data from the db.

Comment: Thank you both! I must say storing the variable in its own table works like a charm!